How to politerly withdraw an application to buy a property?
I'm looking for a way to say politely I'd like to withdraw an application to purchase a house before the contract.
I don't know what it's usage to say more than just "I withdraw".
I have in mind something like:
応募させていただいたXXと申しますが、諸般の事情により、応募を辞退させていただきたくと存じます。 but I'm not sure if these words aren't specific to a different situation (job offer or something).
I'd like to add I thank him for the continuous effort and apologize for the waste of time.
The reason is because of the conditions of the loan.
